# How can i get a drupal 8 database table in a view?

Tags: database, view, drupal-8

I'm trying to build a view with data from the yamlform module in drupal 8, the yamlform module only sends data to the view in a so called 'rendered view' which doesn't allow to use the seperate fields.

i would like to add the tables and fields from the yamlform to the views module. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YAML Form module does not currently expose submission data to Views and/or integrate with the Field API. Hopefully in the near future the YAML Form module will provide [Views integration](https://www.drupal.org/node/2769977) and [Field API integration](https://www.drupal.org/node/2792583). The YAML Form module does provide a [customizable results table](https://www.drupal.org/node/2769977#comment-11422859).

The [Contact Storage](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_storage) module does provide Views integration.